# Задача "Игра" C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Условие задачи на картинке.
Код что я написал ниже:
Почему-то всегда если ввожу большое число(около 1 * 10^10) выдает результат 17:174

[image: Задача]

Не могу понять в чем ошибка, помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

long int a = 0, b = 0, n = 0, x = 0, z = 0;

ifstream inp;
ofstream otp;
inp.open("input.txt");
otp.open("output.txt");

inp >> n;
x = n;

z = 1;

if (n % 2 == 0) {
    while (x > 0) {
        if (z % 2 == 0) {
            b += x % 10;
        }
        else {
            a += x % 10;
        }
        z += 1;
        x /= 10;
    }
}
else {
    while (x > 0) {
        if (z % 2 == 0) {
            a += x % 10;
        }
        else {
            b += x % 10;
        }
        z += 1;
        x /= 10;
    }
}

a = abs(a);
b = abs(b);

if (n % 2 == 0) {
    a = a * 2;
}
else if(n % 2 != 0) {
    b = b * 3;
}

if (n < 0) {
    a = a * 3;
}
else if(n > 0) {
    b = b * 2;
}

otp << a << ':' << b;

return 1;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно работать с вводимым числом как со строкой. Это число само не принимает участия в вычислениях, только суммы некоторых его цифр. А эти суммы будут в очень разумных пределах...

```
string s;
inp >> s;
bool neg = false;
if (s[0] == '-') 
{
    neg = true;
    s = s.substr(1);
}
```

и вперед...

**Update**

Исправленный ваш код (разберитесь сами, что к чему):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    long int a = 0, b = 0;
    bool neg = false;
    string n;

    ifstream inp;
    ofstream otp;
    inp.open("input.txt");
    otp.open("output.txt");

    inp >> n;

    if (n[0] == '-') {
        neg = true;
        n = n.substr(1);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n.length(); i+=2) a += n[i]-'0';
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i+=2) b += n[i]-'0';

    if ((n[n.length()-1]-'0') % 2 == 0)
        a = a * 2;
    else
        b = b * 3;

    if (neg)
        a = a * 3;
    else
        b = b * 2;

    otp << a << ':' << b;

}
```

Comment: Написал код, сижу над ним уже минут 20 исправляю, но не могу понять почему выдает крайне странные значения, можете посмотреть? https://codeshare.io/5DBldk
На базовый пример (ввод - 234932) выводит 316:306

Comment: См. исправленный ответ. `int(char)` дает значение кода символа, а не значение цифры - для этого надо вычислить `c-'0'`.

Comment: Увидел, спасибо. Работает. Не знал что нужно отнимать '0', буду знать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы вводите число 10 млрд. Посмотрите сколько вмещает в себя тип long int. У Вас переполняется переменная.

Comment: Скорее всего, но не факт. ЕМНИП, сейчас размер `long` обычно совпадает с разрядностью архитектуры.

Comment: В условии задачи введенное число может быть N^101. В любом случае будет переполнение

Comment: @Николай Какой тип данных мне использовать если в условии сказано что числа будут до 10^101?

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko, может `string`?  и извлекать по одному разряду - переводить их в числа...

Comment: @Vladimir еще не работал с string, можете привести пример, если не трудно?

Comment: @Vladimir уже нашел как с ними обращаться, сейчас отойду, когда приду попробую сделать с string.

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko, уже Harry ответил :-) .

Comment: @Vladimir я написал неверный код, выдает крайне странные результаты, если вам не трудно - можете посмотреть , может поймете в чем ошибка : https://codeshare.io/5DBldk
На ввод из примера выдает 316:306